# Calling replaceWith gives "not a function" error (replacing text node with mix of text and html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple text nodes which I want to replace some text in it with html:

```
<pre>{
       "data": [
          {
             "source": "<a href=www.e.com>e.com</a>",
             "created_time": "2015-11-13T06:16:09+0000",
             "id": "913680432051814"
          },
          {
             "source": "<a href=www.e.com>e.com</a>",
             "created_time": "2015-11-13T06:16:02+0000",
             "id": "913680355385155"
          },
          {
             "source": "<a href=www.e.com>e.com</a>",
             "created_time": "2015-11-13T06:16:00+0000",
             "id": "913680332051824"
          }
</pre>
```

I want to add `<a>` tag to the id number.

I am trying:

```
x=$("pre")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
  });
```

trying to replace on any element. i am trying with x[0]

```
rep =  x[0].data.replace(//\"id\": \"(.*)\",/, "/\"id\": \"<a href=\"https:example.com/\$1\">$1</a>\"")
```

then try

```
x[0].replaceWith(rep)
```

it says: `x[0].replaceWith not a function`

So how to replace the text with html elements?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below it worked. Using $(this) worked.

```
x=$("pre")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
  })
.each(function(){
 rep =  this.data.replace(//\"id\": \"(.*)\",/, "/\"id\": \"<a href=\"https:example.com/\$1\">$1</a>\"")

  $(this).replaceWith(rep);  //when i used $(this) it worked.
})
```